# Error handling for VBA email merge with differing attachments

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

Below is Excel VBA code that I used to send an email via Outlook to a list of email address. Each email address had a different attached file that needed to be sent. What error handling do I need in this code. Right now all the code does is check that the files all exist before doing email processing. 
The list of emails is in Col A starting at A2, the files to be attached are in Col B starting at B2. The folder path for the files is E11, email subject line is E12 and the body of the email is in an Excel TextBox.

```
    Sub Loop1()
    Dim Body As String, I As Integer, filePath As String, fs
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
          Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    'Create Outlook Session
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Range("A2").Select

    StartRow = ActiveCell.Row
    EndRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Body = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 1")).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text
    For I = StartRow To EndRow
        filePath = Range("E1").Value & "\" & Range("B" & I).Value
        If Not fs.FileExists(filePath) Then
        Range("B" & I).Select
        MsgBox ("The file " & vbCrLf & filePath & vbCrLf _
        & " in Cell B" & I & " does not exist" _
        & vbCrLf & "The macro is cancelled")
        End
        End If
    Next I
    For I = StartRow To EndRow
        filePath = Range("E1").Value & "\" & Range("B" & I).Value
        Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With objOutlookMsg
            .Recipients.Add (Range("A" & I).Value)
            .Subject = Range("E2").Value
            .Body = Body
            .Attachments.Add (filePath)
            .Save
            .Send
    End With
    Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
    Next I
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't really say what you"should" test for, apart from the cases that are likely to happen. As a user it is always nicer and better to get a message that helps me understand what is wrong, so i can figure if i can fix it. Getting VBA's standar End or Debug popup does not help the enduser at all... It can only help the developer...
Here are some ideas of what you test:

- CreateObject("Outlook.Aplication"). Put an On Error goto... Handler around that, so if Outlook cant be created, you can tell the user someting is wrong.
- verify that we are in the right sheet.
- Is the email title filled in? You probably want it to be... There could also be awarning if it is longer than, say, 50 character.
- the folder has to be filled in as well, and you need to verify if the users have entered it with a trailing \ or not before concatenating it with the filename.
- the email has to follow normal email format, meaning no spaces, but letters and numbers and . and _ are ok. perhaps you can verify that the part after @ is correct
- the textbox has to exist. You could use "on error goto..." here as well to verify its existence
- the textbox has to have some content.
- the attachments might be limited in size, so verify that it is not to big.
- use "on error goto..." Also around the statements that create the email. I believe the objOutlook.CreateItem and the .Save and .Send are the ones are more likely to fail.

This is far from everything that COULD be tested, but you have to make your own risk-analysis on where it makes sense to write the extra code.